# Creating a Dropdown with Checkboxes

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a userform and would like to create a Combobox and have Checkboxes in it.
My goal is to select, multiple options at a single time and show them.

I would like to have something like this:

[[image: 1]]

Is it possible and how I can do so?

Any lead would be helpful.

Comment: You cannot put checkboxes in a combobox using VBA, nor can you make a multiselect combobox.

Comment: @braX Should I use a Listbox instead ? with checkbox

Comment: @braX I would like to have something like the above Image

Comment: sorry, i cannot see images

Comment: a listbox is the only way to accomplish multiselect in VBA. If you were using vb.net you would have many more options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is not possible with a dropdown box. But you could do this with a **ListBox**

For this you have to set the Properties for the List Box Like this:
[image]

If you have this, your Form will lock like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can only use a Listbox with Multiselect (see the following code to test):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ListBox1.AddItem "All"
    ListBox1.AddItem "Project Manager"
    ListBox1.AddItem "Project Scientist"
    ListBox1.AddItem "Software Developer"
End Sub

Private Sub Format_Listbox1()
    ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
    ListBox1.ListStyle = fmListStyleOption
End Sub
```

For the DropDown Effect you can add a picture or textbox to change the height of Listbox1....